# How do I map a list of potentially null widgets?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

I'm new to Flutter and haven't found much success in my brief online search for an answer to this, which is the reason for this post.

Here's the code in question:

```
// `myList` can potentially be null. 
children: widget.myList?.map((item) {
  return Text("Hi.");
}).toList(),
```

I'm trying to loop over a `List<String>?` of errors in my stateful widget, inside of the `children:` property of a `Column`.

Dart is telling me that I cannot `map` over a `List<String>?`, and suggests that I use `myList?.map` instead.

However, when I do that, the issue now becomes that `children:` expects a `List<Widget>` and can therefore not accept a `List<Widget>?` ...

I seem to be stuck in circuitous errors, but somehow I feel the solution is simple. I'm still learning about null-safety.

So tl;dr:

How do I reconcile between a potentially null list of widgets, and a property that expects a list of widgets that isn't null?

---

### Solution

```
children: myList?.map((e) => Text(e)).toList() ?? [],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `List` is `List<Widget>?`, you can add simply a `null` check like so:

```dart
children: _widgets?.map((item) => item).toList() ?? [Text('List was null')],
```

If your `List` is `List<Widget?>?` you can change it to:

```dart
children: _widgets?.map((item) => item ?? Text('widget was null')).toList() ?? [Text('List was null')],
```

If you want to map a `List<String?>` inside a `Column`

```dart
Column(
  children: _strings.map((e) => Text(e ?? 'String was null')).toList(),
)
```

**OR**

```dart
Column(
  children: _strings.map((e) => e == null ? Text('was null') : Text(e)).toList(),
)
```

If your `List` is `List<String>?`

```dart
Column(
  children: _strings?.map((e) =>Text(e)).toList() ?? [Text('The list was null')],
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Two issues with this. I think even if it's not null, it will still return `List<Widget>?`, which `children:` won't accept. Second, I don't want anything displayed in the case where there the list is empty.

Comment: My list is really `List<String>?`

Comment: I have checked it with a `Column` which children accepts only `List<Widget>` , and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks just had a look. So when I use that exact format, I get an error which reads: `error: The method 'map' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null')`

Comment: @BarryD. Check the new edit :P It's pretty much like the first.

Comment: Awesome! I took your initial solution and just used the `?`, which worked! I can see that's also what you've kindly edited in. So this works now. Perfect, thanks! The only difference is that I used a ?? [] on the end, because I don't want any fallback content to appear. I'll put the final solution in the OP. Thank you.